# ListBox ItemsSource binding working through code but not through XAML

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-3.0, binding

I have this XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="MyItemsList"                         
     ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}" 
     SelectionChanged="ItemsList_SelectionChanged">
```

The code behind assigns the datacontext of the page to the view model:

```
DataContext = App.ViewModel;
```

My ViewModel object defines MyItems (and I initialize MyItems before setting the DataContext):

```
public ObservableCollection<Item> MyItems;
```

The end result is that my ListBox doesn't display anything. I tried adding items after the binding, and they don't show up either.

What works is if I set the ItemsSource in code instead of in the XAML:

```
MyItemsList.ItemsSource = App.ViewModel.MyItems;
```

Any tips on why this would happen? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

public ObservableCollection MyItems; - Field, but you should use property!

Property with backing field:

```
private ObservableCollection<Item> _myItems = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
public ObservableCollection<Item> MyItems{get{return _myItems;}}
```

If you whant setter, you should implement INotifyPropertyChanged and call OnPropertyChanged("MyItems")

Comment: Good point; but it didn't resolve my issue. If I put a random name as the ItemsSource property in XAML, it also doesn't give me an error (not at build, not at runtime), is that expected? Right now MyItems is a property with { get; set; } and the ListBox is still empty.

Comment: I changed my collection to have a getter return the private collection. It still doesn't work, I guess somewhere else in my code there's a problem. I'll just set the binding through code then because it's taking too much time to figure this out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: There were no binding errors in the VS output window, but I solved my problem by looking at the sample VS project for a databound WP project. I did a few modifications including setting DataContext in the MainPage.xaml.cs constructor. Thanks!